# Interacting with a Printer directly from R

Tags: r

I want to send an output file to a printer directly from within R.

**Example**: Printing a pdf file generated from R script.

Are there any specific packages or functions which can be useful in this case?

Comment: I think you'd need to use `system` or `shell.exec` and interact with the command line.  This would be operating system and printer driver specific.  Here's a post about printing from the command line that may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124808/printing-pdfs-from-windows-command-line