# How to print multiple PDF files in different folders?

Tags: printing, cmd, adobe, ghostscript

An example would be:

Folder 1:
    a.pdf
    b.pdf
    Folder11
      c.pdf
  Folder 2:
    a.pdf
   b.pdf
    Folder21:
      c.pdf

printing all files between folders

And the cmd would have a way to find the file only putting part of the words?
Example

TEXT : ABC*.PDF

PRINT ABCDF.PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** To loop over multiple files recursively:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.pdf') DO echo "%%F"
```

- `dir /s /b *.pfd` finds all pdfs (*.pdf), in all subdirectories (/s), in bare format - ie just the path name (/b)
- DO echo "%%F" just echo's the result to the console.
- `"tokens=*"` adds the whole line into %%F regardless of white spaces / other tokens
- /F makes it run the ('dir ...') command

**2.** To print from command line use: [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124808/printing-pdfs-from-windows-command-line)

```
AcroRd32.exe /t "C:\Folder\File.pdf" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "IP_192.168.10.110"
```

**Note:** Path to AcroRd32.exe must be in your path environment variable

**3.** Putting it all together -- edit -- 'I've added taskkill to close acrord32 after printing

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.pdf') DO AcroRd32.exe /t "%%~F" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "IP_192.168.10.110" & taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe
```

Comment: Very thanks, but would have a command to close the adobe each for?

Comment: Just kill it with `taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe`

Comment: you can help in the seccond example?