# Print pdf file without opening Print Dialog using windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, printing

I want to print a PDF file (url)  from windows application without opening print dialog.

I have tried the code bellow

```
        string pdfUrl="mysite.com/test.pdf";
        string printerName = "Microsoft Print To PDF";
        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            client.DownloadFile(pdfUrl, filePath);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = filePath;
        info.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        //p.WaitForInputIdle();
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        //if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
        //    p.Kill();
```

but getting error in **p.Start();** bellow
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

What is missing?

Please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124808/printing-pdfs-from-windows-command-line

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566537/1469494

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you should use any third party library to printing PDFs.
We are using following C# PDF library
https://pdfium.patagames.com/c-pdf-library/

And yes, this is commercial library, so I don't know if I have a right to place a link here.

Here is a code to print PDF's without any user interaction:

```
public void PrintPdf()
{
    var doc = PdfDocument.Load("c:\test.pdf");
    var printDoc = new PdfPrintDocument(doc);
    PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
    printDoc.PrintController = printController;
    printDoc.Print(); // Print PDF document
}
```