# Select Printer While Printing Hard-copy with python

Tags: python

Platform: Kivy

With this code am able to print a python string variable to the default printer. How can I get a dialog to select a different printer with different margins and layouts as such?

Regular Printing

```
open(self.filename, "w").write(finalString)
os.startfile(self.filename, "print")
```

Desired Output that has print destination example

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print to a specific printer with os.startfile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419763/print-to-a-specific-printer-with-os-startfile)